# Jquery-ui dialog error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Hi huys as you can see here I am having a dialog not found issue . I know this is part of jquery ui which i think i have loaded correctly but it still seems to not be working .

Error:

```html
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function(anonymous function) 
@ fablinker.php:524jQuery.event.handle 
@ jq.js:1936elemData.handle.eventHandle 
@ jq.js:1599
```

And here is my code guys , and help would be great been stuck on this with days now. Thanks

```html
<?php

// //identify which user is logged in so the right profile info can be pulled up from dbase
// session_start();
// $UserN = $_SESSION['UserN'];

// if(isset($_SESSION['UserN']))
// {
// //$CurrentUser = $_SESSION['UserID'];
// $UserN = $_SESSION['UserN'];

// }
// else
// {
// header("location:index.php");
// }

if (isset($_REQUEST["casestudyid"]))
{
 $casestudyid = $_REQUEST["casestudyid"];
}
else 
{
 $casestudyid = "";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Fab Linker</title>
 
 <!--[if IE]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IE.css" />
 <![endif]-->

 <!--[if IE 8.0000]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="IE8.css" />
 <![endif]-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/webflow.css">
  
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fab/main.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fab/style.css" />
 

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fab/jquery.tooltip.css" type="text/css" />

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dolearnfinance-aab51d.webflow.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fab/myFab.css" />



 

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fablinker/jquery/jquery-ui.min.css">
 <script src="js/fablinker/jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/fablinker/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



 
 <script src="js/fablinker/popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/fablinker/jq.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="js/fablinker/fab.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fablinker/jquery.tooltip.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fablinker/jquery.corner.js"></script> 
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   
</head>

<body>

<div id="navscroll" data-collapse="medium" data-animation="default" data-duration="400" class="w-nav navbarone notfixed">
    <div class="w-container"><a href="#" class="w-nav-brand"><h1 class="logo-text">do<span class="pinktext">Learn</span>Finance</h1></a>
      <nav role="navigation" class="w-nav-menu w-clearfix nav-menu"><a href="index.php" class="w-nav-link nav-link">Home</a><a href="about.php" class="w-nav-link nav-link">About</a><a href="contact.php" class="w-nav-link nav-link">Contact</a><a href="#" class="w-nav-link nav-link modal-link">sign in</a>
      </nav>
      <div class="w-nav-button">
        <div class="w-icon-nav-menu"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-section head-section">
    <div class="w-container">
      <h1 class="course-headings">Fablinker</h1>
      <div class="breadcrums-div">
        <a href="index.php" class="w-inline-block breadcrum">
          <div class="breadcrum-text">HOME</div>
        </a>
        <div class="breadcrum next">&gt;</div>
        <a href="index.php" class="w-inline-block breadcrum">
          <div class="breadcrum-text">course</div>
        </a>
        <div class="breadcrum next">&gt;</div>
        <a href="learn_home.php" class="w-inline-block breadcrum">
          <div class="breadcrum-text">Learn</div>
        </a>
        <div class="breadcrum next">&gt;</div>
        <a href="fablinker.php" class="w-inline-block breadcrum">
          <div class="breadcrum-text">Fablinker</div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-section main-section ">

<!--######################################################################################################-->




   <div id="parent">
     <div id="topDiv">
     <!-- <div id="mainmenu">
      <div id="btnNew" class="menuButton">New</div>
      <div id="btnLoad" class="menuButton">Load</div>
      <div id="btnSave" class="menuButton">Save</div>
      <div id="btnDelete" class="menuButton">Delete</div>
      <div id="btnTutor" class="menuButton">Tutor On</div>
      <div id="btnHelp" class="menuButton">Glossary</div>
      </div> -->
      <a href="#" id="btnNew" class="w-button next-lesson fablinker">New&nbsp;</a><a href="#" id="btnLoad" class="w-button next-lesson fablinker">Load</a><a href="#" id="btnSave" class="w-button next-lesson fablinker">Save</a><a href="#" id="btnDelete" class="w-button next-lesson fablinker">Delete</a><a href="#" id="btnTutor" class="w-button next-lesson fablinker">Tutor</a><a href="#" id="btnHelp" class="w-button next-lesson fablinker">Glossary</a>
    </div>

   <!-- Begin Wrapper -->
   <div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Begin Left Column -->
    <div id="leftcolumn">
       <div id="divInputs" class="exerciseColumn">
        <div id="divInputs_SellingAndBuyingGoods"></div>
        <div id="divInputs_OverheadExpenses"></div>
        <div id="divInputs_Funding"></div>
        <div id="divInputs_FixedAssets"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
   <!-- End Left Column  -->
      
      <!-- Begin PnL Col -->
    <div id="content">
     <div id="hdg">
      <h3 class ="fablinkerheading" >Profit/Loss Account</h3>
      <div class="htmltooltip"  id="htt23" style="width: 170px;">
       <p class="tipText" >Is a financial statement which shows the net profit or loss of a business for a given accounting period.It is essentially a statement of the "income generating" performance of the business.</p>
      </div>
      <i class ="i-space" style="color:black;">(Projected)</i>
     </div>

     
      
     <div id="divOutputs_PNL" class="exerciseColumn">
      <div id="divOutputs_Sales_PNL"></div>
      <div id="divOutputs_CashFlow_PNL"></div>
     </div>

      
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      
     <div id="hdg">
       <h3 style="color: black" >Balance Sheet</h3>
       <div class="htmltooltip"  id="htt23" style="width: 170px;">
       <p class="tipText" >
      Is a financial statement which shows the net profit or loss of a business for a given accounting period.   
      It is essentially a statement of the "income generating" performance of the business.</p>
      </div>
      
       <i  style="color:black;">(Projected)</i>
     </div>
     
     
     <br/>
     
     <div id="divOutputs_BS" class="exerciseColumn">
      <div id="divOutputs_FixedAssets_BS"></div>
      <div id="divOutputs_CurrentAssets_BS"></div>
      <div id="divOutputs_CurrentLiabilities_BS"></div>
      <div id="divOutputs_Assets_BS"></div>
      <div id="divOutputs_RepresentedBy_BS"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Content Column -->
    <!-- Begin Right Column ############################################################################################## -->
    <!-- Begin PnL Col -->
    <!-- End Content Column -->


    <div id="rightcolumn">
     <div id="hdg">
      <h3 style="color: black;" >Operating Ratios</h3>
      <div class="htmltooltip" id="htt43"  style="width: 170px;" >
      <p class="tipText">
      The balance sheet is a statement of the financial position of a business at a given date. 
      It is normally based on historical costs and discloses the book value of the assets, liabilities, share capital and reserves.</p>
      </div>
      <i style="color: black;">(Projected)</i>
        
        
      <div id="menu" style="border-style: 2px solid red; padding: 5px;  margin-left: 19px; ;margin-top: -43px; background:#195e93; float:right; width:95px; height: 83px;" class="invisible">
       <div style="padding: 3px; float: right;">
        <a href="#" class="footerLink">Home</a><br/>
        <a href="#" class="footerLink">About Us</a><br/>
        <a href="#" class="footerLink">Support</a><br/>
        <a href="#" class="footerLink">Log Out</a>
       </div>
      </div> 
     </div>

     
       
     <div id="divOutputs_RAT" class="exerciseColumn"> 
      <div id="divOutputs_ProfitLossRatios_RAT"></div>
      <div id="divOutputs_LiquidityRatios_RAT"></div>
      <div id="divOutputs_WorkingCapitalRatios_RAT"></div>
      <div id="divOutputs_GearingRatios_RAT"></div>
      <div id="divOutputs_VolumeRatios_RAT"></div>
     </div>   
    </div>
   <!-- End Right Column -->
     <br>
    </div> <!--  end  -->
   </div> <!--  end of wrapper -->
  </div>


<div id="dlgNew" class="fldialog">
<h3>New Case Study</h3>

Create a new case study.
<br/>
Name:<input type="text" id="newName"/><br/>
Description:<input type="text" id="newDescription"/><br/>

</div>


<div id="dlgLoad" class="fldialog">
Load a case study:
<select id="selCaseStudies">
</select>

</div>

<div id="dlgDelete" class="fldialog">
Delete a case study:
<select id="selCaseStudiesToDelete">
</select>
</div>





<div id="dlgSave" class="fldialog">
Save:<br/>
Name:<input type="text" id="saveName"/><br/>
Description:<input type="text" id="saveDescription"/><br/>

</div>
<!--End Parent Div -->

 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fablinker/BusinessLogic-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fablinker/fablinkerObjects-min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fablinker/jquery.helpify.js"></script>


 
 <?php echo("<script type='text/javascript'>var casestudyid = '$casestudyid';</script>");?>
 
 
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var currentCSName;
  var currentCSDescription;
  var currentCSID;
  var bNotSaved;
  
  $(document).ready(function(){


   $('#wrapper').corner();
   
   bSaved = true;
   
   $('#dlgNew').hide();
   $('#btnTutor').html('Tutor Off');
   $('#btnTutor').addClass('menuButton_Selected');

   initMapObjects();

   // reset the figures

   if (!casestudyid)
   {
    newCaseStudy();
   }
   else
   {
    loadCaseStudy(casestudyid);
    
   }   

   //configureDependenciesForOutputs();

   configureDependencyTree();
      
   recalcAll();


   
   $('#btnNew').click(function(evt){

    
    if (confirm("New Casestudy"))
    {      
     currentCSName = "";
     $('#currentCSName').val("");
     currentCSDescription = "";
     $('#currentCSDescription').val("");
     currentCSID = -1;
     bSaved = true;
     newCaseStudy();
     recalcAll();
    }

    // don't call the home button handler
    //evt.stopPropagation();
    
   });

   $('#btnRecalc').click(function(evt){

    recalcAll();
    //alert("recalc(Netassets_BS)");
    //om["Netassets_BS"].evaluate();
    
   });

   
   $('#topDiv').click(function(evt){

    if (evt.originalTarget == evt.currentTarget)
    {
     window.location.href="userhome.php";
    }
    
   });
   

   
   $('#btnLoad').click(function(evt) {

    // empty the list
    $('#selCaseStudies').find('option').remove();
    // populate the list of case studies
    $.getJSON("dbs/gcsl.php", function(data){

     $.each(data, function(key, value){

      //alert(key + ":" + value);

      $('#selCaseStudies').append("<option value='" + key + "'>" + value[1] + "-" + value[2] + "</option>");
      
     });
    });

    // show the dialog
    $('#dlgLoad').dialog({

     buttons: {

      "Ok" : function() {
       $(this).dialog("close");

       var csd = {};

       csid = $('#selCaseStudies').val();
       //csid = prompt("casestudyid", "1");
       loadCaseStudy(csid);
       
      }, 
      "Cancel" : function() {
       $(this).dialog("close");
      }
     }
    });
    
    
    // don't call the home button handler
    evt.stopPropagation();

    
    
   });
   
   $('#btnDelete').click(function(evt) {
    // empty the list
    $('#selCaseStudiesToDelete').find('option').remove();
    // populate the list of case studies
    $.getJSON("dbs/gcsl.php", function(data){

     $.each(data, function(key, value){

      //alert(key + ":" + value);

      $('#selCaseStudiesToDelete').append("<option value='" + key + "'>" + value[1] + "-" + value[2] + "</option>");
      
     });
    });

    // show the dialog
    $('#dlgDelete').dialog({

     buttons: {

      "Ok" : function() {

       var csd = {};

       csid = $('#selCaseStudiesToDelete').val();
       
       if (confirm("Delete Casestudy")) {
        deleteCaseStudy(csid);
        //alert ("deleting");
        $(this).dialog("close");

        //$.getJSON("dbs/dcs.php?csid=" + csid, function(data){

        //});
        currentCSName = "";
        $('#currentCSName').val("");
        currentCSDescription = "";
        $('#currentCSDescription').val("");
        currentCSID = -1;
        bSaved = true;
        newCaseStudy();
        recalcAll();


       }
      }, 
      "Cancel" : function() {
       $(this).dialog("close");
      }
     }
    });
    
    
    // don't call the home button handler
    evt.stopPropagation();

    
   });
   
   $('#btnTutor').click(function(evt) {

    if ($('#btnTutor').hasClass('menuButton_Selected'))
    {
     $('#btnTutor').html('Tutor On');
     $('#btnTutor').removeClass('menuButton_Selected');
     $('.imginfo').hide();
    }
    else
    {
     $('#btnTutor').html('Tutor Off');
     $('#btnTutor').addClass('menuButton_Selected');
     $('.imginfo').show();
     
    } 

    // don't call the home button handler
    evt.stopPropagation();
    
   });
   
   $('#btnTest').click(function() {
    
    $("#txtSellingPrice").keyup(function(e)
    { 
     alert("hello");
    });
    
    
   });
   
   $('#btnEvaluate').click(function() {
   
    for (var o in om) 
    {
     //alert(om[o].inputDependencies);
     om[o].evaluate();
    } 
     
   });
   
   $('#btnExpand').click(function () {
    
    if ($('#exerciseHeader').height() == 100) {
     $('#exerciseHeader').animate({
      height:"25px"
     }, 500);
    }
    else
    {
     $('#exerciseHeader').animate({
      height:"100px"
     }, 500);
     
    }
    
   });


   $("#dlgHelp").helpify();
   
   
   $('#btnHelp').click(function(evt){

    showHelpForTopic("dlgHelp", 1);


   });
   
   
   $('#btnTest').click(function(evt) {

    showHelpForFlid("dlgHelp", "CostOfSales_PNL");
      
   });

   
   $('.helplink').click(function(evt) {
    alert('hello');
   });
   
   $('#btnSave').click(function(evt) {

    var csd = {};

    csid = currentCSID;
    $('#saveName').val(currentCSName);
    $('#saveDescription').val(currentCSDescription);

    // show the save dialog
    $('#dlgSave').dialog({
 
     buttons: {

      "Ok" : function() {

       $(this).dialog("close");

       saveName = $('#saveName').val();
       saveDescription = $('#saveDescription').val();

       if (saveName != currentCSName)
       {
        // save as 
        csid = -1;
        $('#currentCSName').val(saveName);
        $('#currentCSDescription').val(saveDescription);

       } 
       currentCSName = saveName;
       currentCSDescription = saveDescription;
       
       $.each(im, function(index, value) {
        console.log(index + " " + value.value);
        csd[index] = value.value; 
       });       
       //for (item in im)
       //{
       // csd[item] = im[item].value;
       //}
       var data = "csid=" + csid
          + "&csn=" + currentCSName 
          + "&csdesc=" + currentCSDescription
          + "&csd=" + JSON.stringify(csd);
  
       jQuery.ajax({
        url:"dbs/scs.php",
        data:data, 
        type:"post", 
        success:function(resp){
         currentCSID = parseInt(resp);
         //alert("saved:" + currentCSID);
         alert("saved");
        }, 
        error:function(e){
         alert("failed to save");
        } 
       });
      },
      "Cancel" : function() {
       $(this).dialog("close");
       
      }
     }
    });

    // don't call the home button handler
    evt.stopPropagation();

   });
   
  });
 </script>

 
</body>
<footer>
    <div class="w-container">
      <div class="w-row">
        <div class="w-col w-col-3">
          <h1 class="logo-text">do<span class="pinktext">Learn</span>Finance</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-6">
          <div class="centered">
            <a href="index.php" class="w-inline-block footer-link">
              <div class="footer-link">Home</div>
            </a>
            <a href="about.php" class="w-inline-block footer-link">
              <div class="footer-link">About</div>
            </a>
            <a href="contact.php" class="w-inline-block footer-link">
              <div class="footer-link">Contact</div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="w-inline-block footer-link">
              <div class="modal-link footer-link">Sign In</div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-col w-col-3">
          <div>
            <a href="#" class="w-inline-block social-media fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></a>
            <a href="#" class="w-inline-block social-media fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></a>
            <a href="#" class="w-inline-block social-media fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Assuming that both `jquery.js` and `jq.js` are both versions of jQuery, then that's your issue. You should remove `jq.js` and ensure that whatever version of jQuery you're using is loaded *before* jqueryUI is.

Comment: You also appear to have quite a few HTML errors (for starters you're using HTML5 elements, such as `<nav>` and `<footer>`, in a XHTML document, and the `<footer>` is outside the `<body>`). I would strongly suggest you run your code through a HTML validator and fix any errors it shows. Formatting it to help readability would help a lot too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks for your help I will get on that straight away . Yes I really need to improve alot with my code implementation still trying to learn best practices , Thanks I will let you know how I get on with that